# How to populate an ImageList from a Resource File

Tags: vb.net, imagelist

Just wondering if there is a way to populate an ImageList from a Resource file. I have looked around on the web, but everything seems to have been from back in 2003/2005.

Any advice would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of reading all images in a resource into an ImageList.

```
var dynamicImageList = new ImageList();
var resourceSet = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, false);
if (resourceSet != null)
{
   foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
   {
      var value = entry.Value as Bitmap; //only get images
      if (value != null)
      {
          dynamicImageList.Images.Add((string) entry.Key, value);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
 Private m_clsImageList as ImageList

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    m_clsImageList = New ImageList()
    m_clsImageList.Images.Add("add", My.Resources.add) 
    m_clsImageList.Images.Add("cut", My.Resources.cut) 
End Sub
```

or

```
resources = new ResourceManager("Icons", assemby-containing-icons.resx);
imageList.Images.Add((Image)resources.GetObject("image-resource-name");
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more specific in my question, I meant how to add a large number of images from a res file. I have all the images stored in a separate .resx file. I was hoping to not have to type out 100 lines of imagelist.Images.Add()

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had tried that one already, but it does not seem to work, I think it is for C# not VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping this? i know its an old post but why would you ever type out 100 lines of the same code +- 1 variable?

Comment: Did try looping it at the time. Didn't work. The eventual solution was to add in the images as a single sheet, then get the images using an array of rects. Thanks for your thought though.

Comment: What kinda resource file are you using if i knew i may be able to come up with an answer with / for you ( Some code may be in need  here if you don't mind sharing )